# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in authorization Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, cloudflare

I have a web service with Laravel that solved the **CORS Origin** problem, but the next problem is that requests that have authorization headers return the following error server.

> OPTIONS https://sandbox.example.com / api / v1 / user / net profile :: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I'm currently using cloudflare and wanted to know if this is a CDN or something else on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is preflight requests.
You need allow OPTIONS request. In first you need create CORS middleware

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class Cors
    {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
            ];

            if($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
                // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
                return \response('', 200, $headers);
            }

            $response = $next($request);
            foreach($headers as $key => $value)
                $response->header($key, $value);
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

then add in Http/Kernel.php in array $middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
        // other middlewares
        Cors::class
    ];
```

After it all requests with type OPTIONS will return response 200 with headers.